# PHP DOM problem searching for <w:t> tags in XML

Tags: php, xml, dom

So I have an XML file (XML export of a MS Word file). What I am just trying to do is to replace these two lines:

```
<w:t>Meno:</w:t>
```

And:

```
<w:t>Priezvisko:</w:t>
```

This is a longer XML excerpt:

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00CF175F" w:rsidRDefault="00CF175F">
−
<w:r>
<w:t>Meno:</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
−
<w:p w:rsidR="00CF175F" w:rsidRDefault="00CF175F">
−
<w:r>
<w:t>Priezvisko:</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
```

I am doing it like this:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('file.xml');

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$wts = $doc->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main','t');

foreach ($wts as $wt) {

 echo 1;

 //if ('Meno:' === substr($wt->nodevalue, 0, 5)) {
  //echo 1;
 //}

}
```

That script echoes nothing. Why does the getElementsByTagName not work? There are tens of w:t tags in the XML.

Comment: Sorry, haven't got the time for a full answer. See this: http://de2.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getelementsbytagnamens.php and this: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/

Comment: Thanks, I have already figured it out thanks to Rob Levine. Check my updated answer (the problem was with namespace).

Comment: (sidenote) You can use `DOMDocument::loadXMLFile` to load XML files with DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know php, but almost certainly the problem is that the xml DOM thinks that "w" refers to a namespace that you haven't yet defined. Instead of searching for a "tag" called "w:t", you need to search for a tag named "t" in the namespace that "w" refers to.

For a better explanation of xml namespaces and how to declare them (using "xmlns" in your document, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181888/what-does-xmlns-in-xml-mean).