# Android app Crashed on setContentView

Tags: java, android

I am brand new to android development and the code crashes at the setContentView(R.layout.main).  I don't know why.  I have tried the standard clean and build and restarting eclipse.

Main Code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}
```

Main.xml Code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0.5dip"
                android:background="#000" />
            <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dip" android:layout_marginRight="0dip" />
            <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:background="#696969" />
            <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:background="#000" />
            <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you get the Stacktrace from logcat?

Comment: How would I do that?? Sorry, I am brand new to android.  I normally do iPhone but got myself into a new project.

Comment: If you're using Eclipse with ADT add the View under the window menu.

Comment: change your name it may work.Make it android developer,the error may get solved. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove xmlns from TabHost. There should only be one xmlns in layout xml file.

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

Comment: xmlns attributes meant only for root layout. Any misplaced xmlns attributes should be removed from the layout file. 

As I put in the code, you just need to replace your <TabHost declaration with my code to solve your crash. For more information about xmlns attributes, you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181888/what-does-xmlns-in-xml-mean  or you can do a little google.

Comment: I took out the xmins and sadly the app still crashes when it launches.  Is there anything else that could be going wrong.

Comment: Still crashing? From my knowledge, that is the only error so far. Let me know if u need more help.

Comment: btw, it is not xmins. It is xmlns.