# Android error: You must specifiy a valid layout reference. The layout ID. in elcipse

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I have been working with elcipse for a couple of weeks now. My code has functioned properly but all of a sudden it has stopped working. I get this error,

main.xml: You must specifiy a valid layout reference. The layout ID @layout/required is not valid.

my XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <!--  select between BIN or auction -->
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/AuctionButton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="82dp"
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="showAuctionOptions"
        android:text="Auction" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BINButton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-2dp"
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="showAuctionOptions"
        android:text="Buy it now" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <include android:id="@+id/cell1" layout="@layout/required"/>

        <include android:id="@+id/cell2"  layout="@layout/gray_line" />

        <!--**  Show if Buy it now is selected **-->
        <include android:id="@+id/cell3" layout="@layout/buyitnow" />
        <!-- ** End Buy it now display ** -->

        <!--** Show if auction selected ** -->
        <include android:id="@+id/cell4" layout="@layout/auction" />

        <include android:id="@+id/cell5"  layout="@layout/gray_line" />

        <include android:id="@+id/cell6" layout="@layout/addons" />

        <include android:id="@+id/cell7" layout="@layout/calculate" />      

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

the error is with the first include, however if I remove that, I just get an error with the second include. If I remove all of the include, I get a 'could not resolve R' error within my java code.

What I have tried,

- cleaning the project
- restarting eclipse
- rebooting my computer

this is my AndroidManifest XML file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="toggler.state"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".TogglerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

none of which have worked.Could anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: @layout/required is layout id or name of layout file res/layout/required.xml???

Comment: Well thought out question +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is probably caused elsewhere in the layout. Remove the extra two `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

The `xmlns` is used to define a namespace. Only the top element can have it in most cases.

Take a look at [What does "xmlns" in XML mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181888/what-does-xmlns-in-xml-mean) if anyone wants to read about the `xmlns` explanation.

Also check to make sure your XML files are all lowercase.

Also try to see if you have the correct package specified in your manifest. Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7496766/935779

> It is worth checking in `AndroidManifest.xml`. The attribute package has
>   the correct value.
>
> That is, `<manifest
>   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>   package="your.correct.package.name" ...`
>
> After you change that, the R.java will be re-generated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <!--  select between BIN or auction -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/AuctionButton"
            android:layout_marginLeft="82dp"
            android:layout_width="119dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="showAuctionOptions"
            android:text="Auction" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BINButton"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-2dp"
            android:layout_width="119dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="showAuctionOptions"
            android:text="Buy it now" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <include android:id="@+id/cell1" layout="@layout/required"/>

        <include android:id="@+id/cell2"  layout="@layout/gray_line" />

        <!--**  Show if Buy it now is selected **-->
        <include android:id="@+id/cell3" layout="@layout/buyitnow" />
        <!-- ** End Buy it now display ** -->

        <!--** Show if auction selected ** -->
        <include android:id="@+id/cell4" layout="@layout/auction" />

        <include android:id="@+id/cell5"  layout="@layout/gray_line" />

        <include android:id="@+id/cell6" layout="@layout/addons" />

        <include android:id="@+id/cell7" layout="@layout/calculate" />      

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Try cleaning the project again, make sure you have lower case XML file names or forcing the `R` values to regenerate. I've added a few things to the answer.

Comment: Thanks again, the project was cleaned after deleting the xmlns and I still have the same problem. the android manifest looks fine to me, I have placed it into the above answer just in case there is an error in it.

Comment: Are there any other XML files in your project with a red x? Maybe others have a duplicate `xmlns` property?

Comment: This is what I don't understand, none of the XML files have a red x next to them, only my main activity. When I look at main.xml in graphical view it doesn't show anything, it just states the error.

Comment: XML errors are tough since they are rarely precise. Sadly, I'd suggest looking at each XML and see if you have the duplicate `xmlns` in it to start with. Some errors aren't even reported in Eclipse but cause issues in unexpected places.

Comment: Right I found the error. You had already suggested I do this before but I misunderstood, one of my xml files was called 'displayFee.xml' and when I deleted that file the error went. This was because of the uppercase- I thought only the first letter shouldn't be uppercase, not the entire name. I will award you the best answer as you had suggested that in your previous comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and was able to fix it by providing a layout_width and layout_height to the include tag.