# Parsing twitter API Namespace georss:point Not bound

Tags: namespaces, twitter, georss

We are parsing the Twitter API in our application. This used to be working fine till yesterday, but now we get the following exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.DataBindingException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 37; columnNumber: 577; The prefix "georss" for element "georss:point" is not bound.]
at javax.xml.bind.JAXB.unmarshal(JAXB.java:225)
```

Seems like there is a new XML tag present: georss:point The feed lacks the namespace declaration for the georss microformat and hence an error is thrown. Is someone also facing this issue? Does a work-round exist for this? Because it is bringing my app down currently.

Any help in this regard is highly appriciated. Thanks, Vaibhav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes wkoot removing the geo tag instead as i was not using it anyways then parsing the String now :( the only 2 legitimate solutions for now...

Comment: Of courses this also works. If the offending tags are removed, XML parsers can process the feed fine.

Answer (score 4):

The problem appears to be that the xmlns declaration for georss is missing from the feed since yesterday:

```
xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss"
```

There was a similar issue reported about a year ago (https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/625), seems to have resurfaced. Try adding that declaration.

---

Edit: the current issue has also been posted https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/10491

Comment: I can confirm that adding the namespace of the microformat (http://georss.org/simple#Point) solves the problem.

Comment: You add the declaration on the first line of the feed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181888/what-does-xmlns-in-xml-mean