# android-what is the role of xmlns:myapp in xml layout file

Tags: android, android-layout

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/***.****"
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffffff" >
```

i want to know what is role of xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/my-app-name"... what is need of this , how it works, please help.........

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the namespace in case you use your own attributes for the views.

This is most commonly used when you create your own (or use others) customized views.

For example, if you create your own customized textView which supports using a custom font from the assets folder, you might want to add this:

```
<...MyTextView app:fontFile="fonts/myFont.ttf" .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

It means xml namespace.

Basically, every element (or attribute) in xml belongs to a namespace, a way of "qualifying" the name of the element.

More Information Visit [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181888/what-does-xmlns-in-xml-mean).

Comment: is it necessary every time it will same as name space ?

Comment: it will always be the same for android XML files.

Comment: @NicolasTyler if it will wrong and i upload that on play store than what will happened

Comment: the app should not compile with an invalid namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you wont use the xmlns(ns: name space) ,there could be a conflict between the tag used in another xml file . for eg:

**file1:**

```
<table>
  <name>jad</name>
</table>
```

**file2:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>google</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If these XML fragments were added together, there would be a name conflict. Both contain a  element, but the elements have different content and meaning.

For this major reason a **qualified name space** is used . There are other several use also .