# can not put the ViewPagerIndicator on the ViewPager

Tags: android

i used  https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator ,the lib is very cool,but when i used i meet a question: at the simple_circles.xml :

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

i modify the code :

```
 <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

it give me CirclePageIndicator cannot be cast to android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

edit:who give me -1, can you give some reason.i want to name-calling

Comment: have u added library reference?

Comment: yes.i cannot modify its code,i can run it.

Comment: are you run it ,if you modify it like me?

Comment: let me check i haven't tried it.

Comment: I have tested it and put it as per ur xml..but it gave me same error...and then i reverted back and it ran..!I think we cannot put indicator above the viewpager using this library...@pengwang

Comment: i have solved it,but i cannot  explain it.see my answer

Comment: where is ur answer?@pengwang

Comment: i have post it ,you can see it

Comment: hey is it working? because i m getting error..!

Comment: what is your error?i am is  ok

Comment: can  you post your xml file?

Comment: yes y not...wait i m going to post.and +1 from me.

Comment: are you solve your problem?

Comment: no not solved yet.i m going to post my xml..check it.@pengwang

Comment: @pengwang: can you please see my Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528792/unable-to-send-atz-command-to-elm-327-after-establishing-connection-with-elm327

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <LinearLayout
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent">

           <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
              android:id="@+id/indicator"
              android:padding="10dip"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            />
       <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/pager"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
      />

  </LinearLayout>
```

add  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" to the ViewPager,all is ok,but i donot know why

Comment: ur trick is working...+1 from me...but i m using LinePageIndicator instead of CirclePageIndicator...also i have to change my xml to above that u have mentioned...!

Comment: yes i can run it above the pager...that's y i have given u +1..this trick is working.@pengwang

Comment: check 2nd answer..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181888/what-does-xmlns-in-xml-mean @pengwang