# Web service using JAX-WS... is there something I'm missing?

Tags: jax-ws

I am a Java developer and I have had some exposure to web services in the past but nothing terribly hands on as the project that I'm assigned to right now.

I've been tasked with exposing a web service that will allow another application to push data to the application that I am working on. I was told that the web service must use SOAP 1.2. And that's all that I've been told, so far.

I started by finding a sample web service using JAX-WS. We're using JDK 1.6 so JAX-WS is included, which is good. The sample was very straightforward and I have a working web service with some of the business logic implemented and it has been tested. Next, I am comparing the soap request xml for my web service to a sample soap request xml provided but the other team who will be consuming my web service. My confusion lies in the following:

in my soap request xml, I notice that the syntax is slightly different:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

in the sample soap request xml provided by the other team is as follows:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap:Body>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Am I missing something? Is there something other than JAX-WS used for creating web services?

Comment: Both request are same. S or soap, it won't make any difference. Your webservice should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181888/what-does-xmlns-in-xml-mean), since your question is related to XML namespaces.
Basically what you see, means that namespace prefix name is irrelevant as long as it refers to the same URI, for instance XML parser used by JAX-WS would ignore prefix name and would and consider only URI/element names.