# My XPATH expression is selecting an incorrect node set

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to teach myself XSL and XPATH. I have a sample XML document created by one of our commercial tools, and I want to extract certain node values and create a CSV file as output. A truncated example of the XML document is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<xml_report> 
  <form id= "WOI:WorkOrder" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xforms">
     <mode l>
        < group name="field-info" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <group name="field" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="*">
               <string name="name" />
               <number name="id" long="true" />
               <string name="type" range="closed">
                  <value>CHAR</value>
                  <value>TIME</value>
                  <value>DECIMAL</value>
                  <value>REAL</value>
                  <value>INT</value>
                  <value>ENUM</value>
                  <value>ATTACH</value>
                  <value>DIARY</value>
                  <value>TIMEOFDAY</value>
                 <value>DATE</value>
                 <value>CURRENCY</value>
                 <value>NULL</value>
              </string>
           </group>
           <!-- Additional group nodes -->
        </group>
     </model>
     <instance>
        <field-info>
           <field>
              <name>Work Order ID*&#43;</name>
              <id>1000000182</id>
              <type> CHAR</type>
           </field>
           <!-- Additional field nodes -->
        </field-info>
        <entry>
           <field_value>
              <value>WO0000000498983</value>
           </field_value>
           <field_value>
              <value>New Host name for new server build</value>
           </field_value>
        </entry>
        <!-- Additional entry nodes -->
     </instance>
  </form>
</xml_report>
```

I want to extract the contents of the value elements only, filtering out everything else. I've written some pretty unsophisticated XSL to attempt to do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" media-type="text/plain" />
   <xsl:template match="/xml_report/form/instance">
      <xsl:for-each select="entry/field_value">
         <xsl:value-of select='value' /><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given the example XML, I would expect the following output:

```
WO0000000498983,New Host name for new server build,
```

The issue is that I'm actually extracting the value of ALL elements preceding the node list I actually want to work with, as well as unwanted indents and line spacing. I thought that specifying a restrictive XPATH expression in the template match and for-each tags would suffice, but it does not. How can I narrow the range of selected nodes to only those that I actually want to use? I'm using SAXON as the XSLT processing engine on Windows 7 if that helps.

```
              CHAR
              TIME
              DECIMAL
              REAL
              INT
              ENUM
              ATTACH
              DIARY
              TIMEOFDAY
              DATE
              CURRENCY
              NULL








           Work Order ID*+
           1000000182
            CHAR





           WO0000000498983


           New Host name for new server build
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not get the desired output because of the namespace in your input XML at the form element:

```
<form id="WOI:WorkOrder" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xforms">
```

Therefore all elements in this form have this namespace that is not matched in the XSLT.
When adding the namespace, for example as `xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2000/xforms"`, following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2000/xforms">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" 
          indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" media-type="text/plain" />
<xsl:template match="/xml_report">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="xforms:form"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/xml_report">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="xforms:form/xforms:instance"/>   
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="xforms:instance">
  <xsl:for-each select="xforms:entry/xforms:field_value">
     <xsl:value-of select='xforms:value' /><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your example XML with the correction of `<model>` instead of `<mode l>` in line 4, produces following output:

```
WO0000000498983,New Host name for new server build,
```

To avoid misunderstandings - in this XSLT I've just added the xforms-namespace as `xmlns:xforms`, it is not necessary to name it like that. It would e.g. be possible to declare it as `xmlns:xfo="http://www.w3.org/2000/xforms"` and then change `<xsl:apply-templates select="xforms:form"/>` into `<xsl:apply-templates select="xfo:form"/>` (and also change it for the other elements currently prefixed with `xforms:`).

As you are using XSLT 2.0, it would also be possible to declare the `xforms` namespace as the `xpath-default-namespace`, as you're only targeting elements that are in this namespace. The adjusted XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xforms">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" 
            indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" media-type="text/plain" />
<xsl:template match="//form">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="instance"/>   
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="instance">
<xsl:for-each select="entry/field_value">
     <xsl:value-of select='value' /><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the same output. Because `xforms` is the `default namespace`, it's not necessary to add the extra namespace and prefix the elements.
Another adjustment in this version is to match the `form` instead of the `xml_report`, as the `xml_report` does not have the `xforms` namespace.

As reference for namespaces you can e.g. have a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-decl or valuable answers given at [What does "xmlns" in XML mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181888/what-does-xmlns-in-xml-mean)