# Must an XML namespace name URI be retrievable?

Tags: xml, xsd, wsdl, xml-namespaces, wsdl2java

I have the following tags on my WSDL:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<definitions name="" targetNamespace="http://xxxxx/ws"
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             xmlns:s0="http://xxxxx/ws"
             xmlns:s1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
  <types>
    <xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" 
                elementFormDefault="qualified"
                targetNamespace="http://xxxxx/ws/comments" 
                xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 
                xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" 
                xmlns:s0="http://xxxxx/ws" 
                xmlns:s1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
                xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
                xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
                xmlns:tns="http://xxxxx/ws" 
                xmlns:tnsc="http://xxxxx/ws/comments" 
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                xmlns:y="http://new.webservice.namespace">
```

The types are thereafter qualified to a be in the s0,s1... namespaces.

The question is whether the namespace end-point(="http://xxxxx/ws") needs to be a valid url?
If the endpoint no longer exists - does it mean that we need to re-generate the stub proxy for the Web Service again?

**Note**: The endpoint of the Web Service itself is different from that of the namespaces and does still exist.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Namespaces are URIs that need not be retrievable

> <sub>*From @jww question:*</sub>
>
> The question is whether the namespace end-point(="http://xxxxx/ws")
>   needs to be a valid url?

No, an XML namespace takes the lexical form of a URI but *does not have to be retrievable* according to [W3C Recommendation: Namespaces in XML 1.0 (Third Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-decl):

> The attribute's normalized value MUST be either a URI reference — the
>   namespace name identifying the namespace — or an empty string.   The
>   namespace name, to serve its intended purpose, SHOULD have the
>   characteristics of uniqueness and persistence.  ***It is not a goal
>   that it be directly usable for retrieval of a schema (if any
>   exists).***

### Why are URIs used if they need not be retrievable?

> <sub>*From @jww follow-up in comments*:</sub>
>
> What is the purpose of `http:` if its *not* retrievable? Shouldn't they
>   use something like `null:` to signal its private? Otherwise, how do
>   folks like me know when it's private, and when it's deprecated or
>   withdrawn? I guess what I am asking is, *what is the signalling
>   mechanism?*

Many, including myself, do indeed recommend that the namespace URI be retrievable as a document or as the governing XSD itself.  However, as shown above it is not required.  Further, [a conformant, validating XML processor need not even report when a namespace name is not a URI](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ProcessorConformance):

> To conform to this specification, a processor *MUST* report violations
>   of namespace well-formedness, with the exception that it is not
>   *REQUIRED* to check that namespace names are URI references [[RFC3986](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#URIRef)].

For this reason, you'll sometimes see non-URI used in namespace names, especially for quick, throw-away examples.  (However, it's probably better to use `http://www.example.org/topic` in such cases to be proper.)

***URIs are used because they are a convenient mechanism for expressing uniqueness of a resource with a built-in authority specification*** -- the owner of the domain is the one responsible for namespaces defined using the domain.

### Namespaces as endpoints

> <sub>*From @jww follow-up in comments*:</sub>
>
> If the endpoint no longer exists - does it mean that we need to
>   re-generate the stub proxy for the webservice again?

No, and you should not even refer to the namespace as an endpoint.  The retrievability of the namespace name URI has no bearing at anytime on the specification or operation of your Web Service.

Comment: I'm coming to this much, much later than you wrote it, but it looks like you're saying that the URIs are essentially just convoluted naming conventions. Would the program feasibly work just was well if i changed one of them from "http://xxxxxxx/ws" to "apple" or "abc?

Comment: @NegativeFriction: Lexically, yes, but given that you alone do not control "apple" or "abc", it's not recommended.