# Standard way of publishing xml schemas

Tags: xml, namespaces, xsd

Say I have an `xml` schema, defining the namespace: `http://foo.com/mySchema`. Is there a standard way to publish the schema so that xml instances of the schema will only need to define the namespace and not the `xsi:schemaLocation`?

For example, if you look at imdb's sitemap xml: http://www.imdb.com/sitemap_US_index.xml.gz

The xml defines a namespace: http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 without also defining a schemaLocation.

If you visit this URI, it has 2 xsds there: "siteindex.xsd" and "sitemap.xsd"

My questions are:

1. Is this part of the xml standard? Will every xml parser "know" how to find the schema from the namespace URI?
2. Is there a standalone "xsd repo" tool that helps me to publish xsds under my domain, without the hassle of setting up a web server myself. I'm imagining something with some sort of RESTful API that allows me to `PUT` new schemas, `DELETE` existing schemas and of course `GET` new schemas, using their namespace `URI`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The XML standard does not provide you as the publisher of an XSD with a definitive way to dictate a binding between the XSD's `targetNamespace` and the location of the XSD.

There is no general "xsd repo" tool that manages any sort of well-known repository that can help you in this regard.  There are, of course, many options these days using cloud-based storage facilities (Google Drive, DropBox, Amazon Cloud Drive, etc) to easily publish any file and make it publicly available via a URL.

You're on your own regarding where to publish your XSD.  Keep in mind that [namespace URLs do not have to be retrievable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27613891/290085); there is no requirement that an XSD be there.   Also keep in mind that the binding between a namespace and the physical location of an XSD is the responsibility of the user, not the XSD publisher.  You mention `xsi:schemaLocation` as one mechanism under the XML document author's control for specifying XSD location; another is [XML Catalog](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/14810/xml-catalogs.pdf).