# XHTML5 namespace... Is a final standard or need a W3C update?

Tags: xml, html

The [new 2014's XHTML recomendation say about namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#namespaces),

> The HTML namespace is: http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml

So, a good practice is to add in the root tag of an **XHTML5** file  the attribute `xmlns`,

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">...</html>
```

but, let's see http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml , it is updated?

NO: the last update was 2013-01-16  and about XHTML it say that is "Working drafts", so, perhaps, no final decision about ...

QUESTION: **we can trust** in this namespace declaration? Or we must wait a complete and safe standardization about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For backward compatibility, the same `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace has been used for all versions of HTML since 2000, including XHTML 5.

[W3C HTML5 28 October 2014 Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/) (not draft, meaning the specification process is complete) [says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#namespaces):

> The HTML namespace is: http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml

[WHATWG's HTML: Living Standard — Last Updated 29 January 2015](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/) also [says](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#namespaces):

> The HTML namespace is: http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml

**It is safe to trust the stability of the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace name.**

The presence of a stale "Working drafts" label at the documentation page listed at http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/ does not change the actual recommendation status of HTML5.  You should also know that a namespace URI is a lexical naming construct [which does not even have to be retrievable.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27614076/290085)