# Best way to find and specify XML Schema (XSD) locations

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsi

I've often dealt with sort of problem - *schema locations*. Sometimes you have to write configuration XML file or any other XML file that includes a lot of links like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
```

And every time I have to deal with some instrument I wonder: where should I *look for it*? How could I know what links and options I should use in the header of my XML?

Please, tell me, how do you find out *what is needed* to put in there and *where do you look* for it commonly?

How do you know how exactly *modify* the header if there is need to describe a use of another technology in the same XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to find an XSD

- Look where you're told the XSD resides.
- Look at the URI given by the namespace (although note that [an XML namespace URI need not be retrievable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27613891/290085)).
- Google the URI given by the namespace.
- Google key elements such as the root of the XML.
- Browse XSD compilations such as [XML Standards Library](http://schemas.liquid-technologies.com/).

### How to specify an XSD location

- [How to link XML to XSD using schemaLocation or
  noNamespaceSchemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411871/290085)
- [How to reference a local XML Schema file correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19253402/290085)