# Namespace prefix media on content is not defined

Tags: rss, mailchimp

I'm trying to build a custom RSS feed from scratch, and want to include an image that I can pull out using Mailchimp.

So my current RSS item looks like this:

```
<item>
    <link><?php echo get_permalink($beforeAfter->procedureID); ?></link>
    <media:content url="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url').'/wp-content/uploads/before-after/md/'.$beforeAfter->after_img;?>" type="image/jpg" />
    <?php rss_enclosure(); ?>
    <?php do_action('rss2_item'); ?>
</item>
```

But when I view it, I get the error:

> error on line 15 at column 124: Namespace prefix media on content is
>   not defined

If I remove the `<media:content>` line, the error goes away. Any ideas why the error is appearing, and why it won't read it correctly?

Here are some links I'm using for reference:
http://www.rssboard.org/media-rss#media-content
http://kb.mailchimp.com/merge-tags/rss-blog/feedblock-rss-merge-tags

Comment: Someone please explain the downvote?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See http://www.rssboard.org/media-rss#namespace-declaration:

> The namespace for Media RSS is defined to be http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> <rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
> ```

Include the `xmlns:media` declaration on one of the parent elements of the `<media:content/>` element.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my life! I had no idea why this error was coming up...

Comment: It looks as if the media namespace definition at yahoo is no longer in place: wget http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/
--2018-02-16 19:34:19--  http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/
Resolving search.yahoo.com... 63.250.200.63
Connecting to search.yahoo.com|63.250.200.63|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://video.search.yahoo.com/mrss [following]
--2018-02-16 19:34:19--  http://video.search.yahoo.com/mrss
Resolving video.search.yahoo.com... 63.250.200.63
Reusing existing connection to search.yahoo.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404

Comment: "no longer in place"; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613891/must-an-xml-namespace-name-uri-be-retrievable