# Difference between 2003 and current MSBuild schemas?

Tags: xml, windows, visual-studio, xsd, msbuild

Our project files have been around for a while, and they include `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">`. I'm trying to figure out how to perform a [substring match in a `CONDITION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx) so I thought I would look at the schema to see if something jumped out at me.

Attempting to fetch the schema results in a 404:

```
$ wget http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003
--2016-10-04 22:44:43--  http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003
Resolving schemas.microsoft.com (schemas.microsoft.com)... 65.54.226.187
Connecting to schemas.microsoft.com (schemas.microsoft.com)|65.54.226.187|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
```

When I visited in a Web Browser, Microsoft returned the following message to me, indicating the schema used to be available but its no longer available:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Microsoft has documentation at [MSBuild Project File Schema Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dy88c2e.aspx), but it does not list the schemas available, the schema's URL or the differences between them.

I'm guessing we should *not* be using the 2003 schema since it appears to be deprecated or withdrawn, but I don't know much more beyond that. My questions are:

- What schema should we be using?
- What is the URL to the schema?
- What are the differences between the 2003 schema and the schema I should be using?

---

The versions seems to be more relevant now that we are trying to integrate with AppVeyor. We are having problems with automated testing ([Can't perform 64-bit testing under AppVeyor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43423761/608639) and [Why does AppVeyor use VS2010 tools for VS2015 image?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45474857/608639)), and AppVeyor support is suggesting a change in version numbers in the XML header. Below is the head of a typical VCXPROJ file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The XML Editor for Visual Studio 2015 (maybe other versions as well) provides a cache of schemas locally in `%InstallRoot%\Xml\Schemas`.  Look there for `msbuild.xsd`.

It would be nice if Microsoft provided it at the namespace URI,

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003
```

but [XML namespace name URIs need not be retrievable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613891/must-an-xml-namespace-name-uri-be-retrievable).  Note that the above namespace URI is still [current as of Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255821.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @kjhughes, you are right. There is a bunch of stuff in `%InstallRoot%\Xml\Schemas`. Unfortunately, there's no `2003`, `2005`, `2008`, `2010`, etc. Our project's minimum Visual Studio version is VS 2010. What schema should we use with VS2010? I realize I can use the 2003 one, but I'm happy to use one with more features since we have up-converted over the years.

Comment: Use the 2003 one until Microsoft provides a newer one that better suites you.  Note, however, that there's a school of thinking that stable namespaces ought not change across versions; you'll see this, for example, in W3C namespaces for HTML (`http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`).  **The latest version of an XSD does not necessarily correspond to an updated namespace URI.**