# Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml. Error parsing XML (line-1 : column -1)

Tags: xml, hibernate, jpa, xsd

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="JPAWithEntityManager" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.Student</class>
    <properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpa"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm.2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

> Why is it showing "Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'" .

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is valid against the XSD given by its `xsi:schemaLocation`.

If connectivity to the remote site hosting the XSD was/is an issue, as a quick check, copy the XSD locally and update `xsi:schemaLocation` to the local location.
In the long run, consider using an [XML catalog](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/14810/xml-catalogs.pdf) in order to resolve the reference to a reliable local location.

**See also:**

- [Hosting W3 XML Schema files locally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40403580/290085)
- [How to link XML to XSD using schemaLocation or noNamespaceSchemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411871/how-to-link-xml-to-xsd-using-schemalocation-or-nonamespaceschemalocation)
- [xmlns, xmlns:xsi, xsi:schemaLocation, and targetNamespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202967/xmlns-xmlnsxsi-xsischemalocation-and-targetnamespace)
- [How to reference a local XML Schema file correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253402/how-to-reference-a-local-xml-schema-file-correctly)

Comment: I'd not got what you are trying to stay, can you explain briefly, I had started JPA from today itself, so I'm new to this.I had changed the version to 2.0 from 2.1, but it still not seems to work.

Comment: If this answer does not help, and you're unable to ask a specific follow-up to clarify what's unclear to you, I won't be able to help further.

Comment: The above program is running by adding these 2 properties, can anyone tell me the reason 
` <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
         <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="JPA" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"> 
    <class>com.Student</class>
     <properties>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpa"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
         <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm.2ddl.auto" value="create" />
         <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
         <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
      </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing a hibernate dependency. Try adding

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.4.15.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am not using maven dependency, and the by the way I'd already added the jar which you had mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I had made new project but this time I'd selected another option, i.e "Dicover Annotated Class Automatically", by selecting this tab my program is running.

Comment: Yes now it is working but, i had to create table in database, then only it is able to insert data in the table.