# How to correctly write a DOMXPath query for this XML?

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

I'm writing a script to parse for [this XML](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/?delimiter=/&prefix=98.0.4758.48/).

I want to parse all the `<Contents>` node with [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXpath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). But for some reason, all the XPath queries I tried failed.

My code:

```php
<?php

$apiUrl = 'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/?delimiter=/&prefix=98.0.4758.48/';
$xmlContents = file_get_contents($apiUrl);
if (!$xmlDom->loadXML($xmlContents)) {
    throw new \Exception('Unable to parse the chromedriver file index API response as XML.');
}
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($xmlDom);

// **I tried several $query values here**
$fileEntries = $xpath->query($query, null, false);
if (!$fileEntries instanceof \DOMNodeList) {
    throw new \Exception('Failed to evaulate the xpath into node list.');
}

echo "There are {$fileEntries->length} results\n";
foreach ($fileEntries as $node) {
    /** @var \DOMNode $node */
    var_dump($node->nodeName);
}
```

XPath `$query` I tried:

- `/ListBucketResult/Contents`
- `/Contents`
- `//Contents`

All of these results in "There are 0 results".

If I use `*` in the $query, it will list all the nodes within the `<ListBucketResult>` root node:

```
There are 10 results
string(4) "Name"
string(6) "Prefix"
string(6) "Marker"
string(9) "Delimiter"
string(11) "IsTruncated"
string(8) "Contents"
string(8) "Contents"
string(8) "Contents"
string(8) "Contents"
string(8) "Contents"
```

The easy way is to filter the nodes with the `nodeName` attribute. But I do want to know what went wrong with my XPath query. What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you missed - because you didn't see it in the view given - is, that all nodes are in a namespace, because the root element *really* is

```
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/2006-03-01">
```

So this element and all of its children are in the namespace `http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/2006-03-01`. Adding a namespace like this

```
$xpath->registerNamespace("aws", "http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/2006-03-01");
```

after `$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlDom);` and using it in your XPath expressions like that

```
/aws:ListBucketResult/aws:Contents
```

should solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the URL http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/2006-03-01 gives me an "access denied" response.

Comment: The URI of an XML namespace _doesn't have to be valid_. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27614076/1305969).

Comment: Thanks! This is a bit non-intuitive. The nodes don't really have the `aws:` prefix (or any other prefix) so I didn't think registering namespace was necessary.