# Some questions on XML?

Tags: xml

I know basics of namespaces in XML. Basically they provides the context of that element to processor(processor can be validator,parser,
tranformer etc).

Cotext here means :- say i have two elements with same name elementA . When i prefix p:elementA and v:elementA i am providing
the processor some meta data(processor already knows what to do with this meta data) so that it know elementA with prefix p is different from element with prefix v. **Is that correct ?**

say i have below xml

```
<p:Person
   xmlns:p="http://contoso.com/People"
   xmlns:v="http://contoso.com/Vehicles"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation=
    "http://contoso.com/schemas/Vehicles
     http://contoso.com/schemas/vehicles.xsd
     http://contoso.com/schemas/People
     http://contoso.com/schemas/people.xsd"
     targetNamespace="....">
   <name>John</name>
   <age>28</age>
   <height>59</height>
   <v:Vehicle>
      <color>Red</color>
      <wheels>4</wheels>
      <seats>2</seats>
   </v:Vehicle>
</p:Person>
```

**What is the usage/relevance of schemaLocation and targetNameSpace here or in any xml ?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181888/what-does-xmlns-in-xml-mean

Comment: @emilly It's better to ask one question per question. You basic explanation of namespaces is more or less correct. Schemalocation is explained in the duplicate post.