# Select Nodes with same names and read the Value of one Child of it

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following xml file (shortened).As you can see, i want to get the second "maxtempC" Value.

```
    <data>
      <request>...</request>
      <current_condition>...</current_condition>
      <weather>
        <date>2015-06-12</date>
        <astronomy>...</astronomy>
        <maxtempC>27</maxtempC>
        <maxtempF>80</maxtempF>
        <mintempC>14</mintempC>
        <mintempF>58</mintempF>
        <uvIndex>7</uvIndex>
        <hourly>...</hourly>
        <hourly>...</hourly>
        <hourly>...</hourly>
        <hourly>...</hourly>
      </weather>
      <weather>
        <date>2015-06-13</date>
        <astronomy>...</astronomy>
        <maxtempC>25</maxtempC> //I want this Value
        <maxtempF>77</maxtempF>
        <mintempC>14</mintempC>
        <mintempF>56</mintempF>
        <uvIndex>6</uvIndex>
        <hourly>...</hourly>
        <hourly>...</hourly>
        <hourly>...</hourly>
        <hourly>...</hourly>
      </weather>
    </data>
```

I have tried it using the following:

```
  XElement wData = XElement.Load(query);
  string maxtempC2;
  act_maxtempC2 = wData.Elements("weather")
                           .Skip(1)
                           .Take(1)
                           .Elements("maxtempC")
                           .Value;
```

I have also tried using this:

```
    act_maxtempC2 = wData.Elements("weather")
                           .Skip(1)
                           .Take(1)
                           .Elements("maxtempC")
                           .Select(o => o.Value);
```

But in both cases, it gives not the Value of the Node, just a weird string like this: {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator}

I hope you can Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
        var value = wData.Elements("weather").Skip(1).Elements("maxtempC").Select(e => e.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

The problem with this statement:

```
        var act_maxtempC2 = wData.Elements("weather")
                               .Skip(1)
                               .Take(1)
                               .Elements("maxtempC")
                               .Select(o => o.Value);
```

Is that you never actually evaluated the linq query.  You need to add, say, [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to actually retrieve the string value:

```
        var act_maxtempC2 = wData.Elements("weather")
                               .Skip(1)
                               .Take(1)
                               .Elements("maxtempC")
                               .Select(o => o.Value)
                               .FirstOrDefault();
```

To clarify, [`Enumerable.Take(1)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't project the enumerable into its first element.  Instead, it returns a filtered enumerable containing the first element of the input enumerable.  To project to a specific element, use `FirstOrDefault()` e.g.; [`ElementAt()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is another option.

Comment: Your soultion worked comiling, but as I got through it, act_maxtempC kept on being null.

Comment: @JulCode - is `<data>` the [root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element) of the `query` XML?

Comment: @JulCode - is there anything else present in the root element such as one or more [`xmlns` tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181888/what-does-xmlns-in-xml-mean)?

Comment: @JulCode - My code works with the example given and with the XML example shown [here](http://www.worldweatheronline.com/api/docs/local-city-town-weather-api.aspx).  Suggest you make sure your XML contains what you think by adding a `Debug.WriteLine(wData);` after it's loaded.

Comment: Checked the wData and its all correct. updatet my XML file, maybe I missed soemthing before

Comment: @JulCode - here's a working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ce15YM  So I'm not sure where your problem is.

Comment: thanks it worked now! Found my mistake. I declared wData as XDocument not as var. Thanks for your code that brang me to the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
act_maxtempC2 = wData.Elements("data").ToList()[1].Element("weather").Element("maxtempC");
```

You take the "s" out of Elements

Comment: That soulution gave me an copiling error wich says that I can't idex[] an expression of type "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>" @Andrew
taking the "s" out of the second elemnts does not work :/

Comment: It wasnt the "Elements" part that gave you the error, i forgot to cast it to a list before indexing it, try it now

Comment: It throws an exception, that I have to activate an start index parameter.
How can I realize that?

Comment: Can you paste the exception

Comment: I am using the German version of Visual Studio I do not know weather it helps, but i'll try top translate (and ill paste the exception)

German Exception:
In System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException ist eine Ausnahme vom Typ "mscorlib.dll" aufgetreten, doch wurde diese im Benutzercode nicht verarbeitet.

Zusätzliche Informationen: Der Index lag außerhalb des Bereichs. Er muss nicht negativ und kleiner als die Auflistung sein.

Translation(Hope it isn't too bad)

Further Information: The Index was out of range. It must be not negative and smaller then the listing.

Comment: Still the same Exception