# Unable to parse xml in GO with : in tags

Tags: xml, go

I find that if tags in XML file have `:` in them the unmarshal code in Go does not seem to work. Any insights ?

For example, in the XML file below, `Summary` works but not `Cevent`.

```
<summary>...AIR QUALITY ALERT </summary>
<cap:event>Air Quality Alert</cap:event>
```

```
type Entry struct{
    Summary    string   `xml:"summary"`
    Cevent     string   `xml:"cap:event"`
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cap` is the namespace identifier, not part of the tag name. Here it is shorthand for `urn:oasis:names:tc:emergency:cap:1.1`

(This answer looks like it may have a good condensed explanation of namespaces: [What does "xmlns" in XML mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181888/what-does-xmlns-in-xml-mean))

The Go "encoding/xml" package does not handle namespaces well, but if there are no conflicting tags, you can elide the namespace altogether

```
type Entry struct {
    Summary string `xml:"summary"`
    Event   string `xml:"event"`
}
```

The proper way to specify event, especially in the case of identical tags in different namespaces, would be with the full namespace like:

```
type Entry struct {
    Summary string `xml:"summary"`
    Event   string `xml:"urn:oasis:names:tc:emergency:cap:1.1 event"`
}
```

Here's a working example: https://play.golang.org/p/ry55F2pWKY

Answer (score 4):

`cap` is not part of the tag name, but a namespace identifier (short for `urn:oasis:names:tc:emergency:cap:1.1`, as you've provided in comments). This is the correct notation:

```
type Entry struct{
    Summary    string   `xml:"summary"`
    Cevent     string   `xml:"urn:oasis:names:tc:emergency:cap:1.1:cap event"`
}
```

Mind the space  instead of `:` to denote the namespace. Also note that just using the namespace identifier (like `xml:"cap event"`) **does not work**.

Working example (https://play.golang.org/p/rjkb2esGgv):

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/xml"

type Entry struct{
    Summary    string   `xml:"summary"`
    Cevent     string   `xml:"urn:oasis:names:tc:emergency:cap:1.1:cap event"`
}

func main() {
    xmlString := []byte(`
        <doc xmlns:cap = 'urn:oasis:names:tc:emergency:cap:1.1'>
            <summary>...AIR QUALITY ALERT </summary>
            <cap:event>Air Quality Alert</cap:event>
        </doc>
    `)
    entry := new(Entry)

    if err := xml.Unmarshal(xmlString, entry); err == nil {
        fmt.Println(entry)
    } 
}
```

Comment: This works too. Not sure why one would be chosen over another though or if their equivalent.

Comment: Here's a [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/soUud-lKPe) with a working example.

Comment: @LearnGo: `cap` is the namespace identifier, but doesn't mean anything without the namespace declaration. You need to handle the correct namespace for your document.

Comment: Very new to go and xml. How do we do that in go Here is the code play.golang.org/p/MJKCfSnAIs

Comment: This doesn't work on the actual document, because `cap` isn't the namespace, it's the namespace identifier for that block of the document.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape the colon. So change your xml tag to `xml:"cap\:event"` and it will work as you expect.

```
type Entry struct{
    Summary    string   `xml:"summary"`
    Cevent     string   `xml:"cap\:event"`
}
```

Tested this on the xml page using the unmarshal example with minor modification;

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    type Email struct {
        Where string `xml:"where,attr"`
        Addr  string
    }
    type Address struct {
        City, State string
    }
    type Result struct {
        XMLName xml.Name `xml:"Person"`
        Name    string   `xml:"Full\:Name"`
        Phone   string
        Email   []Email
        Groups  []string `xml:"Group>Value"`
        Address
    }
    v := Result{Name: "none", Phone: "none"}

    data := `
        <Person>
            <Full:Name>Grace R. Emlin</Full:Name>
            <Company>Example Inc.</Company>
            <Email where="home">
                <Addr>gre@example.com</Addr>
            </Email>
            <Email where='work'>
                <Addr>gre@work.com</Addr>
            </Email>
            <Group>
                <Value>Friends</Value>
                <Value>Squash</Value>
            </Group>
            <City>Hanga Roa</City>
            <State>Easter Island</State>
        </Person>
    `
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &v)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("XMLName: %#v\n", v.XMLName)
    fmt.Printf("Name: %q\n", v.Name)
    fmt.Printf("Phone: %q\n", v.Phone)
    fmt.Printf("Email: %v\n", v.Email)
    fmt.Printf("Groups: %v\n", v.Groups)
    fmt.Printf("Address: %v\n", v.Address)
}
```

Remove the escape and it will print "none" for Name. Use a space instead of `:` or `\:` and it will also work. A space in the xml will cause a parse error because it's invalid apparently.

Comment: @LearnGo it very much does. I just tested it and will copy over the full example.

Comment: @LearnGo if this isn't working, please post a more complete example so we can identify what else might be wrong.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/kZ-EtLS27D I have pasted information here. Both the actual xml file and the output and code in the golang page.

Comment: @LearnGo alright, there's a lot more to your actual data. I'll have a look at it when I get some time.

Comment: Thanks so much .Appreciate the help. Its actually an Atom feed So not sure if that is making the difference.

Comment: @LearnGo hey could you make a working playground example that has the xml as a string? Your object definition doesn't match the xml that is posted there however I'm not sure if that was just a mistake in you copying it (xml isn't valid either, you didn't include the closing elements) or an indication that your code needs to be changed. Also, the program just won't run for various reasons, I fixed it so it can but then there is no file to read, so just declare the data as a `[]byte` and pass it into unmarshal directly. If you can do that then I'll make it work.