# Difference between android namespace

Tags: android

What is the difference between given two namespace decalration in Android.

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

and

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

I am getting lint warning on using http://schemas.android.com/tools =>  Suspicious namespace and prefix combination

I know using http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto will solve the issue, but want to know the reason behind it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181888/what-does-xmlns-in-xml-mean

Answer (score 0):

Below namespace is used for android predifined components.

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

But if you want to use custom components like appCompat or your custom defined views you have to use the other namespace as well

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```