# Spring schema folder & Spring XML namespaces

Tags: spring, schema, xml-namespaces

I am looking for how we should determine the symbol of a namespace in Spring bean XML definitions. I guess they are in the Spring schema folder, but I can't find it. For example, what are `c:`, `p:`, `util:`, .. in the XML bean configuration?

Where can I find the schema's for each namespace? For example, how do I know if I should use `http://www.springframework.org/schema/p` in `xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"`, where are the other namespaces and how can I find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose the symbol (`p`, `util`, `jee`, `beans`, ...) by yourself. These are namespaces, and they work by adding the `xmlns` attribute like:

```xml
<beans xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util">
    <!-- Content -->
</beans>
```

In this case we said that `util:` will be used by the util schema, so you'll have to use `<util:properties>` to access things from this namespace. But you could also have said `xmlns:foobar="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"` in which case you could have used things like `<foobar:properties>`.

But you also need to provide the location of the XSD of that namespace by using `xsi:schemaLocation`:

```xml
<beans xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <!-- Content -->
</beans>
```

In this case the XSD for `http://www.springframework.org/schema/util` is available at http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd. The `http://www.springframework.org/schema/util` part is just a label and can be chosen as well. The only thing that has to match is the XSD schema.

For more information about XML namespaces, you should look at [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181888/what-does-xmlns-in-xml-mean).

A list of common XML schema's with Spring can be found in their documentation ([33. XML Schema-based configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html)). However, these only list the core schemas. Some projects (like Spring Web Services, ...) have their own namespaces like:

- http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services.xsd
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd
- ...

You can find the entire list by visiting the [Index of /schema](http://www.springframework.org/schema/). However, like I mentioned, most of these are only used for specific Spring projects, don't just import them, read the specific documentation to find out what you need. The documentation about the constructor namespace (`c:`)  can be found in [7. The IoC container](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-c-namespace).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!