# Python - Element Tree find

Tags: python, xml

I have an xml string that looks something like this:

I am using the Element Tree library

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetCategoriesResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"><CategoryArray><Category><WantedParm1>true</WantedParm1><UnwantedParm1>true</UnwantedParm1><WantedParm2>20081</WantedParm2></Category></CategoryArray></GetCategoriesResponse>
```

I want to get some values of the Category Node, let's call them Wanted Parms 1 and 2. However I am getting an AttributeError probably because the code I wrote is not able to find the child node of the Category item.

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
XML = #Above Code in String
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(XML))
root = tree.getroot()
for Category in root[0]:
    one = Category.find("WantedParm1").text
    two = Category.find("WantedParm2").text
    print(one, two)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  "Having issues" is not a problem description.

Comment: @Prune I am really sorry, I pressed submit while typing the question and it uploaded the form. I'm trying to update it asap

Comment: Understood.  However, you still haven't posted a MCVE so we can reproduce the problem.  Your call to **find** has returned **None**, but that's about as far as I can take you at this point -- in short, what you already suspected.

Comment: @Prune This is pretty much all the code that interacts. What other information would you like to have?

Comment: Cut-and-paste code that reproduces the problem.  I've wrapped the XML structure in triple quotation marks and run the program, but the error I get is a parse failure in **fromstring**: *xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: mismatched tag: line 6, column 29*, which appears to be the start of **</WantedParm1>**

Comment: @Prune I'm really sorry! Could you please try again?

Comment: Yes ... and I can now reproduce the problem.  Fortunately, someone more familiar with ElementTree found the problem for you.  :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The XML elements are in the default namespace `urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents` So all tags get prepended with the full URI of the namespace.

Changing your `find()` parameter to include the URI should work.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
XML = #Above Code in String
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(XML))
root = tree.getroot()
for Category in root[0]:
    one = Category.find("{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}WantedParm1").text
    two = Category.find("{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}WantedParm2").text
    print(one, two)
```

You can find more information on dealing with namespaces on the element tree docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces) or this stack overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181888/what-does-xmlns-in-xml-mean).