# What is the correct way to get PrimeFaces UI locally?

Tags: primefaces

I would like to develop java-webproject using JSF and PrimeFaces working in intranet, without the Internet connection.

In my project now in `index.xhtml` I use this section to get UI components and it works fine.

```
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

But now I want move my app to intranet, so I've got some questions:

1. What (and where) should I download as UI library?
2. Where I should store it in my project locally?
3. What should I write in `xmlns:p=` property?

Sorry in advance for dumb questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What (and where) should I download as UI library?

Consider you want to make a Cake, you need tools, you need rules, the same here with UI library.

> Where I should store it in my project locally?

In the classhpath of your project, if you are using maven, you can just declare the dependency in your `pom.xml`

> What should I write in "xmlns:p=" property?

You have to write  `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"` nothing is change

I think you misunderstood what `xmlns` mean you can take a look about that here [What does "xmlns" in XML mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181888/what-does-xmlns-in-xml-mean)