# Deserialize an XML file to object in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I tried to Deserialize an XML to an object using C#, but I am getting some errors.

My XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:transmission xmlns:ns0="blabla.xsd">
<ns0:DiagnosisErrorResponse>
<ns0:ID>7</ns0:ID>
<ns0:ErrorCode>9</ns0:ErrorCode>
<ns0:ErrorDescription>sometext</ns0:ErrorDescription>
<ns0:ErrorDate>11-12-2018</ns0:ErrorDate>
</ns0:DiagnosisErrorResponse>
</ns0:transmission>
```

I have an entity like this:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "blabla.xsd", ElementName = "ns0:transmission", DataType = "string", IsNullable = true)]
public class DiagnosisErrorResponse
{
    [XmlElement("ID")]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ErrorCode")]
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ErrorDescription")]
    public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ErrorDate")]
    public string ErrorDate { get; set; }
}
```

and my error is:

```
<transmission xmlns='blabla.xsd'> was not expected.
```

My function is this:

```
private void ReadXmlFileByPath(string filePath)
{
    string xmlText = string.Empty;
    XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument(); 

    using (XmlTextReader tr = new XmlTextReader(filePath))
    {
        tr.Namespaces = true;
        d.Load(tr);
        xmlText = d.InnerXml;
    }

     XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DiagnosisErrorResponse), "");

    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlText))
    {
        DiagnosisErrorResponse result = (DiagnosisErrorResponse)xs.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

**Update**: I removed  the 'ns0:' prefix from the `XmlElement` attribute at entity but I still get the same error.

Comment: The namespace prefix `ns0` does not go in the element names. The namespace prefix can be different.

Comment: And the namespaces in the XML (xmlns:ns0) and the XmlRoot attribute should be the same

Comment: @KlausGütter so what to change?

Comment: As @Ben wrote: remove the ns0 from the .cs, i.e. `[XmlRoot(Namespace = "blabla.xsd", ElementName = "transmission", DataType = "string", IsNullable = true)]`, `[XmlElement("ID")]` etc.

Comment: @KlausGütter i did.. but same error yet

Comment: I think they mean remove all references to `ns0:` from your code.

Comment: @spodger so how i will reference between the entity to my xml? i removed the 'ns0:' from the attribute but i still get the same error.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you get the error `: was not expected` if `:` is no longer in your code.

Comment: @spodger my error is :

    <transmission xmlns='blabla.xsd'> was not expected.

Comment: ns0 can remain in the XML but not in the C# code. C# and xml refer to the namespace definition in different ways. XML uses an arbitrary namespace prefix which is needed in the xml. C# uses the Namespace property of the XmlRoot tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your c# data model does not match your XML.  Specifically:

1. You have indicated that the element name for `DiagnosisErrorResponse` should be `"ns0:transmission"`.  The namespace prefix `ns0:` should **not** be included, it is just a lookup in the XML file to find the actual namespace, which is defined by the [xmlns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1181888) attribute `xmlns:ns0="blabla.xsd"`.
2. The XML has a level of nesting not accounted for in your data model.  The XML in your question is not indented; if I indent it, it looks like:

   ```
   <ns0:transmission xmlns:ns0="blabla.xsd">
     <ns0:DiagnosisErrorResponse>
       <ns0:ID>7</ns0:ID>
       <ns0:ErrorCode>9</ns0:ErrorCode>
       <ns0:ErrorDescription>sometext</ns0:ErrorDescription>
       <ns0:ErrorDate>11-12-2018</ns0:ErrorDate>
     </ns0:DiagnosisErrorResponse>
   </ns0:transmission>
   ```

   As can now be seen, `ID` and so on are not children of `transmission`, they are children of `DiagnosisErrorResponse` which is a child of `transmission`.  This needs to be accounted for in your c# classes.

Combining these two issues, your data model should look like:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "blabla.xsd", ElementName = "transmission", IsNullable = true)]
public class Transmission
{
    [XmlElement("DiagnosisErrorResponse")]
    public DiagnosisErrorResponse DiagnosisErrorResponse { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(Namespace = "blabla.xsd", IsNullable = true)]
public class DiagnosisErrorResponse
{
    [XmlElement("ID")]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ErrorCode")]
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ErrorDescription")]
    public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ErrorDate")]
    public string ErrorDate { get; set; }
}
```

And your deserialization code should look like:

```
private DiagnosisErrorResponse ReadXmlFileByPath(string filePath)
{
    using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(filePath))
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Transmission));
        var result = (Transmission)xs.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        return result.DiagnosisErrorResponse;
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lwgElZ).

Alternatively, if you were trying to deserialize just the `<DiagnosisErrorResponse>` element inside the XML file without creating a data model for the root element, you could use `XmlReader` to scan forward in the XML until the appropriate element is found:

```
private DiagnosisErrorResponse ReadXmlFileByPath(string filePath)
{
    using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(filePath))
    {
        if (!xmlReader.ReadToDescendant("DiagnosisErrorResponse", "blabla.xsd"))
            return null;
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DiagnosisErrorResponse));
        var result = (DiagnosisErrorResponse)xs.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mLlq8A).

Notes:

- There is no need to load the XML file into an `XmlDocument`, re-serialize it as a string, then deserialize the string.  The XML can be deserialized directly from a file in one step using an `XmlReader` or `StreamReader`.
- `XmlTextReader` has been deprecated by Microsoft in its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextreader?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks).  [`XmlReader.Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.create?view=netframework-4.7.2) should be used instead.
- You can avoid modeling errors such as the ones above by using one of the code generation tools mentioned in [Generate C# class from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4203540/344280).
- The easiest way to diagnose an error in XML deserialization is to *serialize* an instance of your root type, then compare the resulting XML with the XML to be deserialized.  Inconsistencies are typically easily spotted and indicate where you have problems.